# Return only specific fields from projection array sub-document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking at MongoDB's documentation on the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) and [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch)
projections. I'm trying to figure out how to return only a subset of a 
projection array's fields, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Related posts:

- I am not trying to perform a [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) from [mongodb aggregation framework - Fetch first document's field of the nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15926033/369450).
- Nor am I trying to flatten the sub-document from [Return only array value in mongo projection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14711816/369450) because I still want some fields from the top document.

Say I have the following documents in the `test` collection:

```js
{
    "_id": "A",
    "array": [
        {"key": 1, "name": "foo", "data": {}},
        {"key": 2, "name": "bar", "data": {}}
    ],
    "extra": {}
},
{
    "_id": "B",
    "array": [
        {"key": 3, "name": "spam", "data": {}},
        {"key": 4, "name": "eggs", "data": {}}
    ],
    "extra": {}
}
```

The query I effectively want to perform is:

```js
db.test.findOne({"array.key": 1}, {"array.$.name": 1, "extra": 1})
```

Which I would expect it to only return `name` under the sub-document in the
array where `key` was `1`. E.g.,

```js
{
    "_id": "A",
    "array": [
        {"name": "foo"}
    ],
    "extra": {}
}
```

But if I perform that query, I get this instead:

```js
{
    "_id": "A",
    "array": [
        {"key": 1, "name": "foo", "data": {}}
    ],
    "extra": {}
}
```

Which is identical to doing the query:

```js
db.test.findOne({"array.key": 1}, {"array.$": 1, "extra": 1})
```

I've also tried the following which results in the same:

```js
db.test.findOne({"array.key": 1}, {"array.$": 1, "array.name": 1, "extra": 1})
```

Is there a way to only return a subset of the fields for `array.$`
instead of the whole sub-document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you specifically trying to do this without using aggregate?

```
db.test.aggregate([{$unwind:"$array"},
                   {$match:{"array.key":1}},
                   {$project:{"array.name":1, extra:1}}])
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that aggregation could accomplish what I was trying to do because I'm not aggregating multiple documents.

Comment: But what if you can't use aggregates? I'm a little confused about this, given that you can use the $ operator and access a subfield in an update like this: `db.students.update(
   { _id: 4, "grades.grade": 85 },
   { $set: { "grades.$.std" : 6 } }
)`