# $all type of operator for subdocuments in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, nosql

```
Mongo Document
{"objects":
      { 1 : { Type: "A"},
      { 2 : { Type: "B"},
      { 3 : { Type: "C"},
      { 4 : { Type: "A"}
}
Desired result:
{ 
  1 : { Type : "A"},
  4 : { Type : "A"}
}
```

How do i query the above ***Mongo Document*** to get the above ***Desired result*** ?

Comment: Maybe this post will help [return-only-specific-fields-from-projection-array-sub-document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254363/return-only-specific-fields-from-projection-array-sub-document). But wouldn't it be better if you define value of objects as an Array of objects if allowed, because mongodb has good support for [Array documents projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I went to the standard MongoDB newbie trap assuming that you could have any JSON structure from the fundamental definition of what MongoDB is used for..
Looks we can't query the follow document structure in MongoDB

```
elements:{ 
 1 : { Type : "A"},
 4 : { Type : "B"}
}
```

This is how my final Document looked like:

```
elements: [
 {id: 1, Type: "A"},
 {id: 4, Type: "B"}
]
```

The above document can be queried in MongoDb this way: {"elements.id":1}